# Store value permanently

Tags: windows-phone-7, isolatedstorage

I am new in Windows phone 8. I have an application which required store counter value before close application .and  when I again start  application  counter  start from that value where application was close if date is same. if date is not same than counter start  with 0.

Comment: Where is the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the data in the phones Isolated storage, I suggest you go through the [31 days of windows phone tutorials here](http://www.jeffblankenburg.com/2010/10/15/31-days-of-windows-phone-day-15-isolated-storage/) if you are new to the platform

specifically, read about Isolated storage [here](http://www.jeffblankenburg.com/2010/10/15/31-days-of-windows-phone-day-15-isolated-storage/):

define a class for your data structure or use a KeyValue pair if you prefer

```
 public class AppCounter 
 {
   public Datetime CountDate {get;set;}
   public int Counter {get;set;}
 }
```

In your App.cs, Read this value and increment if required

```
    // Code to execute when the application is launching (for example, from Start)
    // This code will not execute when the application is reactivated.
    private void Application_Launching(object sender, LaunchingEventArgs e)
    {
        ////read instance of AppCounter in IsolatedStorage, if empty initialize for first use and store
        //var appCounter = ReadValue;

      if(appCounter == null) appCounter = new AppCounter();

      if(appCounter.Date != DateTime.Now.Date){
         appCounter.Date = DateTime.Now.Date
         appCounter.Counter++;

        //Save appCounter to Isolated Storage
     }
}
```

remember not to do any heavy memory intensive tasks in this method, the OS will kill your app if it takes too much time to complete any code here or utilizes too much memory.

Answer (score 0):

`IsolatedStorageSettings` provides a simple dictionary to store key-value (string-object) pairs persistently for your app.

```
IsolatedStorageSettings settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;

// save a value
settings["CounterValue"] = cntVal;

// load a value
int cntVal = (int)settings["CounterValue"];
```

Don't forget to cast the retrieved value because only objects are stored.